# Signed measure with Hahn Decomposition

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $\mu$ and $\nu$ are two finite measures on $(S,\Sigma)$ and $\mu \wedge\nu =\mu - (\mu-\nu)^+$. I am trying to prove $\mu \wedge \nu$ is the largest signed measure that is less than or equal to both $\mu$ and $\nu$.

What I tried:

Let $W$ be a set of signed measures  on $(S,\Sigma) $ such that for any  $w \in W$, we have $w\leq \mu$ and $w \leq \nu$.
 I want to prove that $\sup W = \mu \wedge \nu$.

Is it good start? Is it a good idea to use Sup to solve this?
 And, I would really appreciate if you could give me some guide.

Comment: Set-wise supremum of measures is not a measure except in trivial cases. So you cannot use sup.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

note that, from the definitions, we have

$\mu \wedge\nu(E) =\mu(E) - (\mu-\nu)^+(E)=\nu(E)$ if $\mu(E)\ge \nu(E)$

and

$\mu \wedge\nu(E) =\mu(E) - (\mu-\nu)^+(E)=\mu(E)$ if $\mu(E)\le \nu(E)$

Now let $\tau$ be any other signed measure such that $\tau\le \mu$ and $\tau\le \nu$.